# Slow MySQL inserts on one specific machine - what might be wrong with it?

Tags: mysql, performance

My application runs in docker, so I can be sure it's always the same version of MySQL, same DB structure, same collations and so on. I run it on several machines. On all of them my benchmark script which does 20k inserts sequential takes a reasonable amount of time (like 30sec). But on one machine it takes like 13m. Hardware stats are similar in terms of CPU cores and RAM (8 cores, 16 GB). The OS of the critical machine is Debian Bullseye, like on one of the others as well (the others are various Debian or Ubuntu variants).
Why might this specific VM might perform so much worse than the others?

Comment: Something blocking in the OS? Missing driver / os updates. Faulty hardware?

Comment: It's a VM so my knowledge about the hardware is limited. How would you find out i something is blocking the OS? Those VMs are dedicated for the application and more or less fresh, so it's unlikely, but nevertheless...

Comment: That is very difficult to explain in a few sentences, they are many articles about that online, so I would suggest to check those out. But a VM makes it different it could be that the vm runs on a different hosts which is slower or has more VMs running on them

Comment: How long does `SELECT 1;` take?  That would measure the "ping time" to see if it is a network problem.

Comment: Additional DB information request - two sets - one set from 13M server AND one set from faster server, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to find config differences.

Comment: And TEXT results of this query, please. 
SELECT 'SLEEPING Ram use', 
    COUNT(*),SUM(time) as 'time - seconds',SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) 
        FROM information_schema.processlist 
        WHERE 
        command="Sleep"; 
 
from each server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be due to different `fsync` behavior on the two different machines.

You can try to relax data persistence constrains to see if the slow machines suddenly become fast. If so, your issue is related to slow `fsync` (sync writes) performance.

Please note that this ***WILL*** break ACID compliance, so use these setting **only for testing, then revert** to the default parameters. Do ***NOT*** experiment on a production server.

On the slow machine, try setting the following:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
sync_binlog=0
```

Restart `mysql` and re-issue your INSERTs.

When finished, remember to remove these options to restore full ACID and restart `mysql` again.

Comment: Yes. makes it extremely fast!